# Wamp server virtual hosts online

Tags: wamp, virtualhost

I've installed a virtual host on wamp server like him https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18rwvUVoSYU
This works on localhost but nobody can access from the outside, when I put wamp online. Without virtual hosts working properly.

I have folders in my d:\wamp\www directory: 
1. folder1
2. folder2

Please, can someone help?
Тhanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to serve web page, make sure your router's firewall is set to allow connection from outside to port 80 and route it to your machine where WAMP is installed.

Comment: Wamp server works fine from the outside without the virtual hosts. Only when I put virtual hosts getting error
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at my.ip.address Port 80

Comment: Post your virtual host configuration